# Отображение usercontroll в зависимости от выбранного узла treeView

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется:
 - UserControl_1;
 - UserControl_2;

Как сделать чтобы при перемещении по узлам дерева, в зависимости от выбранного узла, в "panel1" отображался "UserControl_1" или "UserControl_2"?
Я сделал как показано в коде ниже.
Будет ли это правильно?

```
 private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {
            string name = e.Node.Text;

            switch (name)
            {
                case "Node_1":
                    UserCntrl_1 userCntrl_1 = new UserCntrl_1();
                    panel1.Controls.Clear();
                    panel1.Controls.Add(userCntrl_1);
                    break;

                case "Node_2":
                    UserCntrl_2 userCntrl_2 = new UserCntrl_2();
                    panel1.Controls.Clear();
                    panel1.Controls.Add(userCntrl_2);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да, это будет правильно

Comment: @Igor После выбора "Node_1" пользователь выбирает "Node_2". Не нужно ли что-нибудь делать с "userCntrl_1"? Если там будут запущены какие-нибудь процессы, они будут продолжать работать?

Comment: да, они будут продолжать. Процессы должны учитывать, что у контрола в любой момент может не стать родителя.

Comment: @Igor Тогда наверное нужно убивать после перехода на следующий узел процессы предыдущего узла(формы)? Как это сделать?

Comment: Я бы не удалял из коллекции UserControl, а просто менял свойство `Visible`, но можно и так. Внутренние процессы привязать к состоянию свойства `Visible` (true/false) или `Parent` (null/!null), как-то так. Но вообще процессы не должны быть прибиты гвоздями к контролу, им место в модельном слое, а контрол пусть себе отражает состояние и не занимается лишними делами.